# NodeJS String to Buffer pdf file

Tags: node.js

Hi guys i'm trying to download a pdf file and save it on my disk. The API send me a string. But the following code not working.

```
axios.get('https://myapi.com/download', config).then((res) => {
  var buff = Buffer.from(res.data, 'binary');
  fs.writeFile('file.pdf', buff, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
  });
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
})
```

I've tried it, and working ...

```
fs.readFile('./download.pdf','binary', function (err, data) {
  var str = data.toString();
  var buff = Buffer.from(str, 'binary');
  fs.writeFile('novopdf.pdf',buff, () => {
    console.log('ok');
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what issue you are facing?

Comment: when i save the pdf from API, it`s save an empty document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to config axios get request as follows

```
const response = await Axios({
 method: 'GET',
 url: url,
 responseType: 'stream'
})

response.data.pipe(Fs.createWriteStream(path)) // path is location where you want to write the file.
```

Then check for end event on the response object.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please upvote the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for PDF files. You can also pass this stream as body in some another HTTP request to send it somewhere else (in my case I had to send this stream to a different web server).